# Show only the activities of friends and mine with BuddyPress

Tags: wordpress, social-networking, buddypress

Is there a possibility in Buddypress to restrict the activities to show only those of friends and mine please ?

When users come to my site the cookie "bp-activity-scope" does not exist, so all activities are displayed (even if both users are not friends). I can force the creation of the cookie with the value to "friends" but it's not the best for security, anyone can easely delete this cookie and view all activities...

Do you have any idea please ? Ideally I would like to show the activities of my friends and mine on the same page.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "BuddyPress Friends Only Activity Stream" plugin